# Dont add NSMutabledictionary values in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to add datas to a dictionary using key value array but the dictionary values are arranged based on keys alphabetical order

my values and keys array contains :

```
myValueArray ={[orange,apple],
               [ford,toyota,lexus]}
myKeyArray ={[fruits],[cars]}
```

I am adding keys and value to a NSMutabledictionary using

```
myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:myValueArray forKeys:MainDelegate.myKeyArray];
```

myDictionary should be

```
  myDictionary = { Fruits =(orange,apple);
                   cars =(ford,toyota,lexus);}
```

but it is added in key's alphabetical order  and looks like

```
 myDictionary = { cars =(ford,toyota,lexus);
                     Fruits =(orange,apple);}
```

is there a way to add key value pairs in dictionary as it is without any ordering.

I am trying this to populate a grouped uitableview. since keys are used as sections everything looks like contacts app where sections and its corresponding values are arranged alphabetically. But i need the recent section to be shown first(the first one in array).

Comment: Why do you need a unsorted dictionary?

Comment: i populate my table view with that

Answer (score 2):

If you need to conserve your initial order, then you have to use an `NSMutableArray`.

`NSMutableDictionary` is designed to be able to access the values for key in the fastest possible way, and having the key sorted helps with that.

Here is how to declare the dictionary and array and how to use them for a grouped tableView:

```
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{ @"cars": @[@"ford" , @"toyota", @"lexus"], @"Fruits": @[@"orange", @"apple"]};
    NSArray *keysArray = @[ @"Fruits", @"cars"];

    // first section
    NSString *sectionName = keysArray[0];
    NSArray *sectionArray = myDictionary[sectionName];

    // second section
    sectionName = keysArray[1];
    sectionArray = myDictionary[sectionName];
```

Comment: how to use nsarray are u talking about nsarray's -setvalue:foKey:

Comment: No. Array don't have key and values, they only have objects. So you would do an `addObject:`.

Comment: see my edited question. I wanted to populate grouped table view

Comment: In this case, keep using the dictionary that you have, but create also an array for the key name in the order that you need. When you're using it get the section name from the array, and the elements for cells from the dictionary but based on the key names saved in array.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableDictionary` doesn't have any sorting associated to it, when you print this in log, it will display in sorting order.

You can manage a separate `NSMutableArray` and put you `key` in the order in which you want to fetch from `NSMutableDictionary`.

That can be the easiest way to store values and fetch as per your requirement.

May this help you.

Comment: my datas are dynamic i dont know exactly wat key i will be having

Comment: Are you adding data in NSDictionary?

Comment: see my edited question to know what exactly i am trying to achieve.